# WP filter/actions

Tags: filter, action

I'm trying to alter WP post titles BEFORE they go into the database.  Here's what I've (see commented out actions/filters).  None seem to work.
Thanks!

```
<?php

function filter_post_numbers( $data , $postarr ) {
    // Change post title
    $unwantedNumbers = array('8 of ','9 of ','10 of ','11 of ','12 of ','13 of ','14 of ','15 of ','16 of ','17 of ','18 of ','19 of ','20 of ','21 of ','22 of ','23 of ','24 of ','25 of ','26 of ','27 of ','28 of ','29 of ','30 of ','31 of ','32 of ','33 of ','34 of ','35 of ','36 of ','37 of ','38 of ','39 of ','40 of ','41 of ','42 of ','43 of ','44 of ','45 of ','46 of ','47 of ','48 of ','49 of ','50 of ','51 of ','52 of ','53 of ','54 of ','55 of ','56 of ','57 of ','58 of ','59 of ','8','9','10 ','11 ','12 ','13 ','14 ','15 ','16 ','17 ','18 ','19 ','20 ','21 ','22 ','23 ','24 ','25 ','26 ','27 ','28 ','29 ','30 ','31 ','32 ','33 ','34 ','35 ','36 ','37 ','38 ','39 ','40 ','41 ','42 ','43 ','44 ','45 ','46 ','47 ','48 ','49 ','50 ','51 ','52 ','53 ','54 ','55 ','56 ','57 ','58 ','59');
    foreach ($unwantedNumbers as &$word) {
    $word = '/\b' . preg_quote($word, '/') . '\b/';
}
$data['post_title'] = preg_replace($unwantedNumbers, '', $data['post_title']);
}
//add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'filter_post_numbers' , '99', 2 );

//add_action('pre_post_update', 'filter_post_numbers');

add_filter('content_save_pre', 'filter_post_numbers', 10, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to return a value.

so

```
return $data;
```